# PHP: Laravel Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have files 2018_08_23_042408_create_roles_table.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('role_name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('roles');
}
}
```

and 2018_08_23_042521_create_users_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('avatar_link');
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['role_id']);
    });
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

yet when I ran php artisan migrate I got this error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key 
 constraint (SQL  
: alter table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign 
key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`))                                                                                                             

[PDOException]                                                          
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

And when I ran php artisan:reset it always shows error like 'Base table exists' and I have to run php artisan tinker and Schema::drop('users') to fix that.
I have read similar question on stackoverflow but nothing worked. Any insight of what caused this? Thank you.

Comment: Use unsigned types for foreign key columns: `$table->unsignedInteger('role_id');`

Answer (score 4):

You have to use unsignedInteger to role_id, because it is unsinged int in your database (you use increments). And then try to migrate.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

just give `unsigned` on `role_id`.
change

```
$table->integer('role_id');
```

into

```
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
```

This is because the foreign key is unsigned integer.

Comment: thank you, solved. i miss the unsigned() in user table.

Answer (score 0):

For managing the `foreign key` relationship two tables must have the same datatype column and the parent table column must be a `primary key` or an `index column`. In your case `role_id` column is an integer and in `users` table `id` column is not an  integer that's why the error is.

So make these two column identical in terms of `datatype` and try again.